# rct websocket issue in xcode?

Tags: xcode6, react-native

[image]

Here I'm getting an error. I am using xcode-beta 8.0 software. When I run the project I am getting this error. I want to run react-native project. I always run the RTCWebsocket error. Here I am getting two errors: one is .h file and another one is .m file in RTCwebsocket.

1) I am working on MAC OSX 10.9.5 (Maverics) and XCode-beta 8.0
2) when run the project "built failed" like this error coming
3) The simulator is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fix of the root cause, but it should get you building.

If you click on Build Settings and then scroll down to 'Apple LLVM 8.0 - Custom Compiler Flags' and remove -werror -wall from 'Other Warning Flags' your build will pass.

This will get reverted if you run npm install, so the owner of that package will need to either change the build settings or fix the compile warnings.

edit:  The base package looks to be fixed with react-native 0.33.0